# Necessary To Subscribe My Youtube Channel

Tags: html, forms

im doing a form that **necessary to subcribe my youtube channel** how can i do that ? like **gleam.io** system but when signing up it needs to subscribe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more information we are left to guess at what would help your situation. In order to process something like this, you're most likely going to need a stronger, more processed language to work alongside HTML such as PHP, .NET, JavaScript or one of the many other choices.

Your `<form>`'s processing will need to pass to information to YouTube or another third party API which has access and the methods necessary to control who is and who is not subscribed.

Comment: thanks that was what i want two hear because i don't know what should i use

Comment: Any of those listed can typically communicate to and with an API (or send information requests to it such as in this case). You may want to look into using jQuery as it makes posting AJAX calls like this (through `$.post()`) easier to digest. In the end it will really depend on your API. Most API publishers will have a developmental kit or information on how to do what you're looking for somewhere in their reference material.

Comment: Thanks im going to study more...